# Concatenate strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a problem with concatenating strings in Python. I need to concatenate the string clave and cadena_aleatoria(x) while cadena_inicio is smaller than 256. This is my script:

```
import sys
import random

x = random.randint(0,9)
def cadena_aleatoria(x):
    cadena = []
    cadena.append(x)
    while len(cadena)<10:
            x = random.randint(0,9)
            cadena.append(x)
    b = "".join(str(i) for i in cadena)

    print(b, end = "")


def cadena_inicio():
    clave = "5275328525062135755"
    cadena = clave + str(cadena_aleatoria(x))
    while len(cadena)<256:
            cadena = clave + str(cadena_aleatoria(x))               
    print(cadena)
cadena_inicio()
```

Comment: do you mean `cadena += clave + str(cadena_aleatoria(x))` ?

Comment: Your questions says "while cadena_inicio is smaller than 256," but your code says "while len(cadena)<256" -- could that be part of the problem?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to `cadena`  not reassign each time through the loop.

You need to also check `while len(cadena + str(cadena_aleatoria(x)))` as you may go over once you add `str(cadena_aleatoria(x)))` to `cadena` inside the while after your check.

```
while len(cadena + str(cadena_aleatoria(x))) < 256:
      cadena += clave + str(cadena_aleatoria(x))
```

You also need  `return(b)` if you don't want to add `None's` to your cadena string

```
def cadena_aleatoria():
    cadena = []
    cadena.append(x)
    while len(cadena)<10:
            x = random.randint(0,9)
            cadena.append(x)
    b = "".join(str(i) for i in cadena)
    return b

def cadena_inicio():
    clave = "5275328525062135755"
    cadena = ""
    while len(cadena + cadena_aleatoria(x)) < 256:
            cadena += clave + cadena_aleatoria(x)
    print (cadena)
```

Your first function can be done using a `list comprehension` :

```
def cadena_aleatoria():
    return "".join([str(random.randint(0,9)) for x in range(10)])

def cadena_inicio():
    clave = "5275328525062135755"
    cadena = ""
    while len(cadena + cadena_aleatoria()) < 256:
            cadena += clave + cadena_aleatoria()
    print (cadena)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems.

First, you're not returning anything from the function `cadena_aleatoria(x)`, so calling it, is returning `None` and you don't want to add `None` to your string. So if you want to return `b`, you should `return b`.

The other issue is that you're not adding any length to cadena in the while loop. You probably want to do this:

```
cadena += clave + str(cadena_aleatoria(x))
```

You're also not returning anything from `cadena_inicio()` but maybe this is intentional.